# Conditional formatting cells based on 3 conditions

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a list of vehicles with start date and end date in sheet1 and a list of dates in sheet2. I need to highlight cells in sheet2 using conditional formatting.

The image is attached for reference.

**This is what I actually mean:**
Lookup value `A11` in the array `A2:C4`, then conditional format cell range `A12:A21` depending on the start date `(b2:b4)` and end date `(c2:c4)`.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use Countifs in a case like this to see if the current date is within any of the given date ranges:

```
=COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$4,$A$11,$B$2:$B$4,"<="&A12,$C$2:$C$4,">="&A12)
```

[image]

The values in B12:B21 are just put in as a check and are not used.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use two helper cells - label them start and end - and fill them using regular vlookup based on the input cell A11.

start E12:

```
=vlookup($A$11;$A$2:$C$4;2;FALSE)
```

end E13:

```
=vlookup($A$11;$A$2:$C$4;3;FALSE)
```

Then setup the formatting rules of the A12:A21 range based on the values of these two helper cells. In the wizzard that is the last option **Use a formula to determine which cells to format**.

The formula might look like this

```
=and(A12>=E12;A12<=E13)
```

EDIT: I haven't realized that the input value may repeat, sorry. In that case COUNTIFS or array formulas must be used.

Comment: Some systems will use "," instead of the ";" as the argument separator.

Comment: vehicle number will be repeated multiple times with different start date and end date . vlookup wont give me a proper result.